# Nested Python Dictionary with Variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

*Why I'm writing this code:* I'm attempting to create script that pulls data from excel and drops it into PowerPoint. It should detect the tab color to indicate if multiple charts appear on the slide.

So far, the data seems to be pulling into the data_dict variable appropriately, charts meant to be on the same slide are not all pulling in only the *very last* chart data ends up in the slide_data dictionary.

```
slidecount = 0
for wksht in wb.sheetnames:
        combinecount = 1
        if tabcolor is not None:
            if tabcolor == most_recent_tabcolor:
                combinecount += 1
                slidecount -= 1
            else:
                combinecount = 1  # Resets to one
            most_recent_tabcolor = tabcolor
        else:
            combinecount = 1  # Resets to one

        '''
        Placed after combinecheck para place correctly in dictionary 
        '''
        infolist = [intended_chart, data_question, data_base, forcefloat, forcepercent]
        slide_data[slidecount] = {}
        slide_data[slidecount][combinecount] = {'Chart Data': data_dict, 'Chart Info': infolist}
        slidecount += 1
```

I expected the following output:
0, {1: { 'Chart Data' ... } 2: {'Chart Data' ... } 3: {'Chart Data' ... }}

I get:
0, {3: {'Chart Data' ... }}

Comment: "slidecount = 0" should be initialize before the "for" loop

Comment: Thank you. My example was incorrect, but it was correct in the code.I've updated the question.

Comment: what is inflolist?

Comment: Shouldn't you move `slide_data[slidecount] = {}` out of the loop?? You are overriding slide_data[slidecount] every iteration of the loop not implementing it.

Comment: infolist is a list of non-data items related to the chart that have to be inserted into the dictionary so charts can be imported properly later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the command:

```
slide_data[slidecount] = {}
```

it wiped out all of the data in the slidecount, but I needed to have something like it to actually add more into the nested dictionary. I created this above the iterations over the wkshts:

```
    dictcount = 0
    while dictcount <= len(wb.sheetnames):
        slide_data[dictcount] = {}
        dictcount += 1
```

This could create some empty dictionary entries, but I should be able to filter them out later.

Answer (score 0):

slidecount is always 0 only if tab color is not none. There is no increment for that variable, just decrement when tab color is none.

I wanted to post this as a comment but i don't have enough reputation to do that.